# Does Intel 865 chipset support DDR2?

Tags: motherboard, compatibility, ddr2

I am looking for a socket 478 motherboard for my old 3GHz Pentium 4 HT processor & found a 865chipset board which claims DDR2. But I am not sure if 865 really supports DDR2 ?

Here is the link to product : http://cgi.ebay.in/NEW-INTEL-P4-865-CHIPSET-SOCKET-478-wLan-w-2Sata-DDR2-/330454803433?cmd=ViewItem&pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item4cf0a423e9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel 865 chip-set doesn't support DDR2.

They didn't introduce DDR2 support until the 915 chip-set generation.

Check out Wikipedia's info on it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Pentium_4_Chipsets).

Intel's info on the 865G chip-set's memory compatibility (specifically on the Intel D865GBFL board) is [here](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d865gbf/sb/CS-027111.htm):

> The Desktop Board D865GBF has four
>   DIMM sockets and supports the
>   following memory features:
>
> - 2.6 V (only) 184-pin DDR SDRAM DIMMs with gold-plated contacts
> - Unbuffered, single-sided or double-sided DIMMs
>     with the following restriction:
>     Double-sided DIMMs with x16
>     organization are not supported.
> - 4 GB maximum total system memory
> - Minimum total system memory: 64 MB
> - Non-ECC DIMMs
> - Serial Presence Detect
> - *DDR400, DDR333, and DDR266 SDRAM DIMMs*

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The specifications pdf on page 13 (Under revision History) says it supports DDR(type1) 266, 333, 400, no mention of DDR2

http://www.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/252514.htm